# Multi-Line list item when text is to wide for the list

Tags: html, css, list, multiline

I have an html list with a certain width, that is used for displaying chat messages. But when the chat line is to wide for the list, it just gets cut off, and doesn't show the rest of the chat message.

I want to get the remaining characters to be displayed on a next line in my list, but still in the same `li` element, as I use different styles for odd and even list items.

I hope I made myself clear, and thanks for the response.

HTML:

```
<div id="top">
    <p id="welcome">Welcome to the lobby!</p>
    <nav>
        <ul id="chatList"></ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#chatList {
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
height: 800px;
background: rgb(140, 140, 140);
}

#chatList li {
margin-top: 0px;
height: 20px;
padding-left: 5px;
}

#chatList li:nth-child(odd) {
background: rgb(180, 180, 180); 
}
```

Zeno

Comment: Can you post the relevant code and css?

Comment: With a normal list with a limited width you shouldn't have this problem as it would break line automatically. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u68vovqg/ .You may have some other style that is forcing that behavior.

Comment: some `overflow: hidden` set on one of the parents ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove the `height` from `#chatlist li`

```
#chatList li {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5akvw8ys/)**